# Disable Visual Assist X for certain project types

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-assist

Is there any way to disable Visual Assist X for all project types but C/C++?

I'm switching a lot between C++ and C# projects, and I way prefer Resharper for handling C# projects. I know I can enable/disable Visual Assist manually through the toolbar, but is it possible to configure it so it will be disabled by default unless it's a C/C++ project?

Thanks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

After speaking to their support line it seems as if it's not possible. However you can tell Visual Assist to ignore certain file types, such as .cs.

Visual Assist X Options -> Projects -> File Handling and then add .cs

It's not exactly what I wanted, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable your uncommon used one (Resharper, Visual assist ) from visual studio extentions (not to uninstall it) and enable when you develop need only